# HTTP POST Method appears empty in Firefox Developer Edition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, firefox-developer-tools

I am using Firefox Developer Edition and Visual Studio 2017 to develop an ASP.NET MVC app. I am sending in data to my app using a form. I can see the data coming into Visual Studio, but when I look at the Network section in the developer tools of Firefox, the POST request is listed but it appears as empty.

> "No headers for this request"

[image: firefox]

[image: visual-studio]

If I try to debug it using Google Chrome, then I don't even see the POST request listed.

[image: chrome]

Here is the action for the view.

```
public ActionResult New()
{
    var membershipTypes = _context.MembershipTypes.ToList();
    var viewModel = new NewCustomerViewModel
    {
        MembershipTypes = membershipTypes
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Here is the form for the view.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Customers"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Customer.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Customer.BirthDate)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer.BirthDate, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Customer.IsSubscribedToNewsletter) Subscribed to Newsletter?
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Customer.MembershipTypeId)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Customer.MembershipTypeId, new SelectList(Model.MembershipTypes, "Id", "Name"), "Select Membership Type", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
}
```

Here is the action for the POST method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Customer customer)
{
    return View();
}
```

I have a put in a break point for the return since I currently don't return anything in the view. But if I continue debugging I get a server error, as expected.

> "The view 'Create' or its master was not found or no view engine
>   supports the searched locations."

However, at this point, the POST method is populated with data when I inspect it in the browser.

[image: firefox2]

Why is this? Should I not be able to see the POST method header data being sent to the server, even before a view is returned to the client? I am running everything on my localhost, including the database.

I expect to see the form data I am sending to the server, at the break point, as you see here below. I can see the same in Chrome, but only after returning a view.

[image: firefox-form]

Answer (score 1):

> "The view 'Create' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations."

This is because `Create.cshtml` is missing.

The way you have set it up needs two views:

```
public ActionResult New()
{
    return View(viewModel);          // New.cshtml
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Customer customer)
{
    return View();                   // Create.cshtml
}
```

As to Firefox not fully displaying the request in F12 when you expect it to -  Firefox and the other browsers are not perfect. It is annoying but I am unaware of any fix.

Perhaps you should report it to Mozilla as a bug?

Comment: So it's more like a general problem then with many browsers? But if I recall correctly, when I used some older version of Firefox and Visual Studio 2015, I was able to see the form data immediately. Even before returning any view. Something must have changed in one of these programs, or maybe in the way the latest IIS works. As you can see, it affects Chrome as well, not only Firefox. Reporting it to Microsoft is probably more appropriate.